# What's the comparative and superlative of shy and dry?

Tags: spelling, superlatives, comparative

What's the comparative and superlative of shy and dry?
I've found you can either keep the y or change it for ier / iest.

shyer - shyest or shier- shiest
Dryer -dryest or drier - driest

Also more shy and more dry.

They reasoning for keeping the y being that unlike friendly or ugly, the y is strong and sounds like /ai/

Comment: Look it up in a dictionary.

Comment: I did. They say different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are English words with disputed or multiple spellings, e.g., [buses & busses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/plural-of-bus); [theater & theatre](https://www.broadwayworld.com/article/Theatre-vs-Theater--Whats-the-Difference-20200802); [draft & draught](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/using-draft-and-draught); and [hiccup & hiccough](https://kris-spisak.com/writing-tip-hiccup-vs-hiccough/).

In some case they're regional differences - use *colour* in the UK, *color* in the US. In some cases, orthography has changed over time. And, unlike other languages which formalized spelling, such as French with the [*Délégation générale à la langue française et aux langues de France*](https://nadeaubarlow.com/the-real-story-of-the-french-language-police/), English spelling rules have been set by a *few* arbiters. So what is the student to do? After due diligence, consulting dictionaries with conflicting answers, ask the instructor what's preferred... being aware that the *next* instructor might have differing views! C'est la vie.

Answer (score 2):

As these Google Ngrams searches show, both varieties exist. If there's a clearly preferred spelling, it's in bold.

[dryer/drier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dryer_ADJ%2Cdrier_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
[**shyer**/shier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shyer%2C%20shier&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)
[dryest/**driest**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=driest%2Cdryest&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) (my spellchecker doesn't even accept "dryest")
[**shyest**/shiest](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shyest%2Cshiest&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Your first ngram is going to match hits for the noun dryer (which is also apparently spelled drier).

Comment: @Laurel I'd fix it, but Ngrams is only returning single word searches for me right now

Comment: Doesn't [`_ADJ`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dryer_ADJ%2Cdrier_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) work?

Comment: @Laurel Never saw that before!